# In Java8, when will the merge function be triggered in Collectors.toMap?

Tags: java, java-8, merge, collectors

I want to transform a `Hashmap<String,Long>` to a `Treemap`, in order to sort its key by string.length (I can't simply use `treemap.addAll` because I have may other logic when insert and I want to use java8)

The code is below. But when keys with same length exist in the initial Hashmap, it will trigger the merge function which throws Exception(I intent to do it because there won't be same string in my case). I wonder why the merge function be triggered since the JavaDoc of toMap() says "If the **mapped keys** contains duplicates (according to Object#equals(Object)), the value mapping function is applied to each equal element, and results are merged using the provided merging function."  I think that in my code the  "mapped keys" should be the entry in hashMap mapped by `Entry::getKey` but not `string.length()` in the TreeMap comparator. i.e. "abc" != "def". So it shouldn't trigger the merge. But?? What the hell?

```
public class TestToMap {

    public static Map<String, Long> map1 = new HashMap<String, Long>() {
        {
            put("abc", 123L);
            put("def", 456L);
        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Long> priceThresholdMap = map1.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
                                      Entry::getValue,
                                      throwingMerger(),
                                      () -> new TreeMap<String, Long>(
                                          (a, b) -> {
                                              return a.length() - b.length();
                                          }))); // this will trigger merge function, why?
        //() -> new TreeMap<String, Long>(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).thenComparing(String::compareTo))));  // but this won't trigger merge function 

    }

    private static <T> BinaryOperator<T> throwingMerger() {
        return (u, v) -> {
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("priceThresholdMap has duplicate v1 %s,v2 %s", u, v));
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

According to toMap() source code, it create a accumulator which will fold each element from source stream into map.

```
Collector<T, ?, M> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                                Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
                                BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction,
                                Supplier<M> mapSupplier) {
        BiConsumer<M, T> accumulator
                = (map, element) -> map.merge(keyMapper.apply(element),
                                              valueMapper.apply(element), mergeFunction);
        return new CollectorImpl<>(mapSupplier, accumulator, mapMerger(mergeFunction), CH_ID);
    }
```

And in Map.merge() , when get("def") will return the exist oldValue=123, which key is "abc", because by the comparator I give to TreeMap "def" is equal to "abc". And then oldValue!=null calls merge function.

```
 default V merge(K key, V value,
            BiFunction<? super V, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(remappingFunction);
        Objects.requireNonNull(value);
        V oldValue = get(key);
        V newValue = (oldValue == null) ? value :
                   remappingFunction.apply(oldValue, value); // call the merge function
        if(newValue == null) {
            remove(key);
        } else {
            put(key, newValue);
        }
        return newValue;
    }
```

ref:[Collectors toMap duplicate key](https://javadevcentral.com/collectors-tomap-duplicate-key#Java_8_Collectors_toMap_code)

Comment: Instead of looking into the source code, you should have looked into [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-). Or read the other answer.

Comment: From the documentation you don't know actually each element from source stream will be pass into Map.merge() and then call the comparator in TreeMap and then call the custom merge function. Document only says the custom merge function will be called when the mapped key are duplicate, but when and who judge the duplication is implicit.  I think it's apt to mistake that duplication judgement should be done after the key-mapping and before the insertion to the TreeMap

Comment: How should it work otherwise? You get a map as result and a map can’t have duplicate keys (according to its own definition of equality). So the map’s definition of key equality matters. When you don’t merge the values of `"abc"` and `"def"`, because you don’t consider them as equal, but produce a result map which can only have one of these keys, what should happen?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just didn't know who trigger the merge , because there is no merge function in TreeMap and when TreeMap.put encounter a value with duplicate key , it just replace the old value. From the toMap() source code I know this work is done in the accumulator by calling Map.merge().

Comment: `TreeMap` has a `merge` method; it’s the one inherited from the `Map` interface.

Comment: It's my mistake. But TreeMap never use it itself.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it should trigger a merge. The merge function is used to merge values having identical keys in the output `Map`, which in your case is a `TreeMap`.

In a `TreeMap`, keys are identical if the `Comparator`'s `compare` method returns `0`, so two keys having the same length are deemed identical, and their corresponding values should be merged.

Note that your `Comparator` causes the output `TreeMap` not to implement the `Map` interface correctly, since the ordering it defines is not consistent with `equals()`:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a tree map, like any sorted map, and
>   whether or not an explicit comparator is provided, must be consistent
>   with equals if this sorted map is to correctly implement the
>   Map interface

(From `TreeMap` Javadoc)

If you want to sort the `String`'s by length, you can still be consistent with `equals`:

Instead of

```
return a.length() - b.length()
```

use

```
return a.length() == b.length() ? a.compareTo(b) : Integer.compare(a.length(),b.length())
```

Now unequal `String`s having the same length will be ordered lexicographically, while `String` having different length will be ordered by length.

Comment: For posterity: Your consistent-with-equals comparator can also be implemented using `comparingInt(String::length).thenComparing(naturalOrder())`.